# how to move nodes from begining to the end in linked list? C

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, temp

i want to build a program which takes K elements from the begining of the linked list and putting them in the end of the linked link, kinda spin. 
for example : if there is linked list : 1->2->3->4->5
and k = 2 then the linked list will look like that : 3->4->5->1->2
here is my try, please help me:

```
void spinfunc(struct node *node_ptr)
{
    int k = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int temp;
    printf("enter a number of the lements from the begin to be deleted - ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    while (node_ptr != NULL)
    {
        if (count + 1 <= k)
        {
            count++;
            printf("count: %d", count);
            temp = node_ptr->data;
            node_ptr->data = NULL;
        }
        node_ptr = node_ptr->next;
    }
    printf("%d ", temp);

}
```

Comment: why not consider using double linked list? are you meant to use only single linked list?

Comment: @CherubimAnand yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in a more simple steps.

We only need to change the next pointer of kth node and tail node of list i.e.

```
kth node -> next = null
tail node -> next = head
```

And then update the head to (k+1)th node.

Overall logic:

*Traverse the list from beginning and stop at kth node. Store pointer to kth node. We can get (k+1)th node using kthNode->next. Keep traversing till end and store pointer to last node also. Finally, change pointers as stated above.*

```
struct node* spinFunc(struct node *head)
```

{

```
int k = 2; //assuming k = 2 
// list = 1->2->3->4->5.
struct node* current = head;
struct node* newHead = NULL;

int count = 1;
while (count < k && current != NULL)
{
    current = current->next;
    count++;
}
//Now current is pointing to node 2 

// current points to kth node. Store it in a variable.
struct node *kthNode = current;

// current will point to last node i.e. node 5 after this loop
while (current->next != NULL)
    current = current->next;

//last node -> next = head
current->next = head;

//update the head now
newHead = kthNode -> next;

kthNode->next = NULL;

//return the new head
return newHead;
```

}

Comment: can you please write the func ?

Comment: @Anand_Barnwal i need to do the algoritem with out copying the linked list

Comment: This is not copying of list. You are modifying the same list.

Comment: If you do not want to return from function then you need to pass the address of head to spinFunc(). Otherwise you won't be able to update the head.

Comment: @Anend_Barnwal okay ty but last question , how to call the function?

Comment: Simply use "spinFunc(&head)" statement and on receiving use "void spinfunc(struct node** node_ptr)". And please accept the answer if it fulfills your requirement.

Comment: @Anand_Barnwal i have a problem i tried your code and its deleting all the nodes , and i can see only the first 2 of the list

Answer (score 0):

Personally an approach that I like to take to this sort of problem is to have a circularly linked list. Rather than the last node in your linked list pointing to Null, instead point it at the first node in your list. Another trick with this type of list is to keep a reference to the last node, not the first. Your problem is now solved just by changing the reference to your list by the correct number of nodes.

Other advantages of a circularly linked list are that appending to the beginning or end is now trivial, this advantage comes without making the other operations in your list any harder.